# How to make a dynamic variable value global in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to make a global variable that always changing?

I want to create something like `protected $global_data;` in `controller` `Global_data.php` that can be called by a lot of controller, and return variable `$global_data` value to whenever `controller` that has `$this->load->library('../controllers/Global_data')`.

But when I tried to call it, it gives me this error `Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`, so I think `CodeIgniter 3.1.8` not allowed me to do this.

So how to achieve what I'm looking for? do I need to put it on `model` instead, `library` file or is there another way to do it?

Thank you.

Here is `Global_data.php` content

```
protected $global_data;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->global_data = array(
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
    );
}
```

`Can_be_anything_controller.php` content

```
class Can_be_anything_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('../controllers/Global_data');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->global_data;
        $data['page_title']     = 'Dashboard';
        $data['page_directory'] = 'pages/dashboard';
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a library for that in `libraries` directory

`Global_data.php` file

```
class Global_data{
  public $global_data;

  protected $CI;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();
  }

  public function common_data()
  {

    $this->global_data= array(
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
        'can_be_anything'    => 'can_be_anything',
    );
    return $this->global_data;
  }

 public function any_method(){
   $query = $this->CI->db->get('table_name');
 }
}
```

Now you can load it in any controller like

```
$this->load->library('Global_data')
```

Then use data

```
$data = $this->Global_data->common_data();
```

Also you may use `HMVC` model to use any method in any controller

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: Ah I see, never read about this `HMVC` thanks! and 1 more question, how to make `$CI =& get_instance()` global in library? so I can call it without redeclare it each function? I tried `private $ci_instance;` `$this->ci_instance = get_instance();` `$CI =& $this->ci_instance;` but it doesn't do the magic, thank you

Comment: In library constructor `$this->CI =& get_instance();` and anywhere in library you can access `$this->CI->whatever`.

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya check my edited answer for `get_instance()` example

Comment: Ah I see, I thought somehow I can replace `$this->CI->` to `$CI->` instead, Thank you :D

Comment: I'd suggest setting `global_data` in the constructor and `common_data()` simply returns it. Then you don't need to build the array each time the data is requested.

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya yes you may use `$CI` instead `$this->CI`

Comment: but $CI will require every instance be written out with get_instance() as its not a property of the class (library).

Comment: @DFriend in my case, the `$global_data` value can be anything, so it depends on which `controller` called it.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam how to do that? I already tried it by remove `this->` but it gives me an error `Undefined variable: CI`

Comment: Then you need a way to have the values change based on that condition don't you?

Comment: The line `protected $CI;` creates a class property that is available to every method of the class and is accessed using `$this->CI`. Without that property you do have to use `$CI = & get_instance();` in every method.

Comment: as @Alex mentioned, you will require to instance in each method like `$CI=& get_instance();`

Answer (score 2):

Make a `MY_Controller` in `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $global_data;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->global_data = 'whateveryouwant';
    }

    public function somemethod() {
        return '123';
    }
}
```

then any other controllers in your `application/controllers` that need to access `global_data` should extend it like so:

```
class Somecontroller extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {
         echo $this->global_data;
         echo $this->somemethod(); // works with methods too
    }

}
```

If you need to run more complex code just put everything into a library or model and autoload it. All `public` methods and properties are globally available. HMVC seems overkill for what you want.

Comment: Why I don't found this solution  in google, this is what I've been looking for! but sorry I already accepted @Rejonaul_Alam first, but thanks! I'll do this later, but for now I already using the `library` way

Comment: Don't mean to step on anyone's toes but accepting is only permanent after some time ;) In the end choose whichever is better for you. Thanks for the upvote regardless.

Comment: Sure, but I hope your answer will be helping somebody else that wants to use the `controller way` :)

Comment: This method already exists on stack for some time. There is actually a good article on it here: https://codeinphp.github.io/post/controllers-for-frontend-and-backend-in-codeigniter/ .. I use this same method for auth and public areas of sites.

Comment: Damn that's a good stuff, why I never step on that article before. Thanks for sharing it with us!

Answer (score 2):

This kind of data can also be handled very nicely by config files.

/application/config/global_data.php

```
<php

$config['foo'] = "some foo";
$config['bar'] = 42;
$config['baz'] = array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

In a controller load the config file with

```
$this->config->load('global_data');
```

The access the items using

```
echo $this->config->item('foo');
echo $this->config->item('bar') * 2; //outputs 84
$data = $this->config->item('baz');
```

[Config documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html)

Comment: But with config, it'll be static. What I need is the dynamic variable, thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: You can change config variables on-the-fly. They will exist in their set state until script execution ends, like any other variable not stored in the db. The other two answers yield the same results.

Comment: Ah never thought of it, it'll be perfect for some cases, I think I'm gonna use this method soon enough

Comment: To be honest, the only "true" dynamic variable that doesn't require being set consistently if its default state is different then its "required" state is a session variable.